# Monkeyrunner doesn't support signal.SIGALRM

Tags: timeout, monkeyrunner

Monkeyrunner hangs from time to time.
I am using the following code from the web. (Sorry, I forget the source.) 
This code is used to detect the "Monkeyrunner hang issue" and reconnect.

```
class Timeout():
    """Timeout class using ALARM signal."""
    class Timeout(Exception):
        pass

    def __init__(self, sec):
        self.sec = sec

    def __enter__(self):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, self.raise_timeout)
        signal.alarm(self.sec)

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        signal.alarm(0)    # disable alarm

    def raise_timeout(self, *args):
        raise Timeout.Timeout()
def snapshot():
    while (True):
        try:
            with Timeout(2):
                return(mdevice().takeSnapshot())
        except Timeout.Timeout:
            print "========================= snapshot timeout ==============="
            mdevice(1)
```

However, the following error is reported:

```
  File ".\lib\monkeySetting.py", line 30, in __enter__
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, self.raise_timeout)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SIGALRM'
```

How can this be solved?

Or is there another way to solve the "Monkeyrunner hang issue"?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `SIGALRM` is not implemented on Windows:

> On Windows, signal() can only be called with SIGABRT, SIGFPE, SIGILL,
>   SIGINT, SIGSEGV, or SIGTERM. A ValueError will be raised in any other
>   case.

On the other hand, you should try [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient), and I hope you solve the *hang* problem and don't need SIGALRM at all.